# Assistance needed with flutter app saving user authentication status

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have an app where Users can currently log in (using phone auth) and log out from the home screen. But whenever the app gets refreshed the user logs out automatically.
What I want to do is to keep the user logged in till he pressed the log out button.

Since I am new to flutter and coding in general it would be helpful if you can help me with the exact code.
[image]

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const LoginScreen();
  }
}
```

**login.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'otp.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_field/intl_phone_field.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  String Country = '';
  final TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Phone Auth'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Column(children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Phone Authentication',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //Phone feild

            IntlPhoneField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                ),
              ),
              controller: _controller,
              initialCountryCode: 'IN',
              onChanged: (phone) {
                debugPrint('Below is phone number');
                debugPrint(phone.completeNumber);
                debugPrint('Country code is: ${phone.countryCode}');
                Country = phone.countryCode;
                // phone.countryCode = _controller2 as String;
                debugPrint(Country);
              },
            ),
            // Container(
            //   margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 10, left: 10),
            //   child: TextField(
            //     decoration: const InputDecoration(
            //       hintText: 'Phone Number',
            //       prefix: Padding(
            //         padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            //         child: Text('+91'),
            //       ),
            //     ),
            //     maxLength: 10,
            //     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            //     controller: _controller,
            //   ),
            // )
          ]),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        OTPScreen(_controller.text, Country)));
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Next',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**otp.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';

class OTPScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phone;
  final String countryCode;
  const OTPScreen(this.phone, this.countryCode, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _OTPScreenState createState() => _OTPScreenState();
}

class _OTPScreenState extends State<OTPScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late String _verificationCode;
  final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final BoxDecoration pinPutDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color.fromRGBO(43, 46, 66, 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    border: Border.all(
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(126, 203, 224, 1),
    ),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('OTP Verification'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Verify ${widget.countryCode} ${widget.phone}',
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Pinput(
              length: 6,
              // fieldsCount: 6,
              // textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
              // eachFieldWidth: 40.0,
              // eachFieldHeight: 55.0,
              // focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
              // controller: _pinPutController,
              // submittedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
              // selectedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
              // followingFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
              // pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.fade,
              onSubmitted: (pin) async {
                debugPrint('submit pressed');

                try {
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                          verificationId: _verificationCode, smsCode: pin))
                      .then((value) async {
                    if (value.user != null) {
                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                          (route) => false);
                    }
                  });
                } catch (e) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  _scaffoldkey.currentState!.showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(content: Text('invalid OTP')));
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _verifyPhone() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '${widget.countryCode}${widget.phone}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                  (route) => false);
            }
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          debugPrint(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verficationID, int? resendToken) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verficationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _verifyPhone();
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late String uid;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: () async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
                  (route) => false);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(uid),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One perfect way is to store the data in shared preferences. All you need in to add the flutter shared_preference package [https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences].

CONFIGURATION

1. After adding this package, create a shared_preference object like: *  final preference = await SharedPreference.getInstance*
2. Next you can store the logs on the mobile storage using the preference object. For example, to store a variable isAuthenticated(which stores the authentication as bool) status of the user, do something like: *  await preference.setBool("authentication", isAuthenticated)*
3. Step three, create another method to retrieve the data from storage.
   *first create another preference object loke in step one(1)*. But this time instead of setBool, use getBool like:*  final isAlreadyAuthenticated = preferences.getBool("authentication")*
4. Now isAleadyAuthenticated holds the value whether is user already login or not and can you can use it to display a login screen of the value is false

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested, but somehow it is still not working. Can you please see this https://github.com/Ankitkj1999/study_lpu/tree/integrating_firebase

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673189/how-to-implement-phone-authentication-using-getx-and-firebase-in-a-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using firebase, i recommed you add the firebase_auth package. And then you wrap the MyApp with a stream builder and supply FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges as stream to the stream parameter which comes with the firebase_auth

So in the builder of the stream builder, return the MyApp() if snapshot.hasData, else return the OTP screen